# Google Apps Script update properties with Trigger

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am creating a script to collect specific datas from Gmail to Google SpreadSheet. Because there are too many mails the execution time is over 6 minutes so i want to use triggers to automaticaly run the script every 6 minutes. My idea is too use Script Properties to store the ID of the last appended thread in order to get it back at the next script execution and keep gathering datas from other threads.

The problem is: when i manualy start the script the Properties are well updated but when the Trigger does it the Properties are not updated. Do you have any explanations ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, never mind, i have found the problem, so for any one having the same one:

Don't try to test your script with an ui.alert when using a Trigger, it was firring an error and prevented the correct execution of the instructions after that.